# verification failed in firebase Number/OTP

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have already launched the app on Playstore but when i try to login( send OTP)  through number and OTP I am getting an error ---- **We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. try again later**

I am getting this error on all device that I try to run the app on, after downloading from the playstore.
But if i run the app in debug mode on my phone after connecting with usb c, then it checks for recaptcha and then sends the otp perfectly. but it does not work in the apk or the app downloaded from the playstore. I have also tried removing the recaptcha but still does not work.
this is my code for otp authentication..

```
enum LoginScreen { SHOW_MOBILE_ENTER_WIDGET, SHOW_OTP_FORM_WIDGET }

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();
  LoginScreen currentState = LoginScreen.SHOW_MOBILE_ENTER_WIDGET;
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String verificationID = "";
  String phoneNumber = "";
  int timerDuration = 60; // Initial timer duration in seconds
  late Timer _resendTimer; // Timer for resend functionality
  bool isResendButtonEnabled = false;

  Future<void> savePhoneNumberToFirestore(String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      // Get the current user's UID
      String userUid = _auth.currentUser!.uid;

      // Convert the phone number to a string
      phoneNumber = phoneNumber.toString();

      // Update the 'number' field in the user's Firestore document
      await FUNCTIONs.firestore.collection('users').doc(userUid).update({
        'number': phoneNumber,
      });

      print('Phone number saved to Firestore: $phoneNumber');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving phone number to Firestore: $e');
    }
  }

  void signInWithPhoneAuthCred(AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
    try {
      final authCred = await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      if (authCred.user != null) {
        bool userExists = await FUNCTIONs.ifUserExistsWithDetails();

        if (userExists) {
          print('User exists, moving to HomeScreen');
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
          );
        } else {
          print('User does not exist, creating user in Firestore');
          await FUNCTIONs.createNewUser();

          // Debug print to check phoneNumber value before Firestore update
          print('Phone number before saving to Firestore: $phoneNumber');

          await savePhoneNumberToFirestore(phoneNumber);

          // Debug print after saving phoneNumber to Firestore
          print('Phone number saved to Firestore: $phoneNumber');

          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddNameScreen()),
          );
        }
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('FirebaseAuthException: ${e.message}');
      if (e.code == 'invalid-verification-code') {
        // Show an error Snackbar for incorrect OTP
        Dialogs.showSnackbar(context, "ENTER CORRECT OTP");
      } else {
        // Show a generic error Snackbar
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Some Error Occurred. Try Again Later'),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      // Show a generic error Snackbar
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Some Error Occurred. Try Again Later'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  
  Widget showMobilePhoneWidget(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.transparent);
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    // Function to validate if the entered number has exactly 10 digits
    bool isValidPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
      return phoneNumber.length == 10;
    }

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white, // Set the background color to white
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text(
                "Verify Your Phone Number",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/number1.jpg",
                height: screenHeight * 0.3,
                width: screenWidth * 0.6,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: screenWidth * 0.7,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter
                          .digitsOnly, // Allow only digits
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                          10), // Limit input to 10 characters
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      prefixText: "+91 ",
                      hintText: "1234567890",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  String phoneNumber = phoneController.text;
                  phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(
                      RegExp(r'\D'), ''); // Remove non-digits
                  if (isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
                    phoneNumber = "+91$phoneNumber";
                    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
                      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                      verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {},
                      verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) {
                        print(
                            "Verification Failed: ${verificationFailed.message}");
                        // Show a snackbar with the actual error message
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content: Text(
                                "Verification Failed: ${verificationFailed.message}"),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      codeSent: (verificationID, resendingToken) async {
                        setState(() {
                          currentState = LoginScreen.SHOW_OTP_FORM_WIDGET;
                          this.verificationID = verificationID;
                          this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                        });
                        // Show a snackbar for OTP sent
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            content: Text("OTP sent to $phoneNumber."),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationID) async {},
                    );
                  } else {
                    // Show a snackbar for an invalid phone number
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text("Enter a 10-digit number."),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: const Text("Send OTP"),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Why am i not getting the otp in the app / apk but getting it in the debug mode.
Please Help me with this error